# publish command is keep failing to windows azure

Tags: azure

My publish command to Windows Azure keep failing. In Visual Studio I am getting the following error message:

> 4:48:58 PM - Preparing deployment for  with Subscription ID:  < mysubscriptionid >
>   4:48:58 PM - Connecting...
>   4:48:59 PM - Verifying storage account 'pwcstorageend'...
>   4:49:01 PM - Uploading Package...
>   4:50:39 PM - Creating...
>   4:51:43 PM - The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
>   4:51:43 PM - Stopping mvc3appsample
>   4:51:45 PM - The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
>   4:51:45 PM - Deployment failed

Note: The publish command was working before.

Comment: Any chance you're running Fiddler? It messes with the auth.

Comment: no. thanks for the tip, i can use fiddler now.

Comment: Fiddler was the cause for me, shutting it down solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit such problem where things were working at one time and after some time not, it is always good to update the environment so you know that if something changed is back to normal.

This problem is very much related with your development machine certificate configuration and due to certificate mismatch the SSL connection can be established. Actually I was able to reproduce  this problem by removing the exact same certificate at the Management portal which I was using for deployment from Visual studio.

To solve this problem you can download the latest publishsettings from Windows Azure Management Portal as described below and use it with Visual Studio:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/05/10/downloading-windows-azure-publish-settings-subscription-configuration-file.aspx

Once you have proper certificate settings between your development machine and Windows Azure Management Portal, the SSL connection can be established and publish will work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the management certificate that is installed on your machine is no longer valid on your Azure Subscription

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was because one of our Azure subscriptions randomly when into (disabled) mode, requiring an escalated support ticket with Microsoft. I suspect that triggered the management certificate error reported by other folks on this question.